# JSOM: The curse of the vanishing TaxonomyFieldValue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, jsom, taxonomyfieldvalue

I have a SharePoint Add-In that is examining files in document libraries across a farm. These document libraries ostensibly share a Managed Metadata site column, which I hope to be able to extract Custom Properties of.

However, I have a problem when introducing SP.Taxonomy.js. I have no problem in getting back an anonymous object of the term when this library is *not* included in the project.

```
//In SPContext (Singleton class)
public static GetItemDetail(itemurl: string): Promise<SP.ListItem> {
    return new Promise<SP.ListItem>((resolve, reject) => {
        SPContext.WebFromNewHost(itemurl).then(contentWeb => {
            let itemPath: string = new URL(itemurl).href.replace(contentWeb.get_url(), '');
            let itemRelativeUrl = decodeURIComponent(`${contentWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl()}${itemPath}`);
            let file: SP.File = contentWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(itemRelativeUrl);
            SPContext.ClientContext.load(file, 'ListItemAllFields');
            SPContext.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                (sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs) => {
                    resolve(file.get_listItemAllFields());
                },
                (sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestFailedEventArgs) => {
                    reject(args.get_message());
                }
            );
        });
    });
}

//In File class
SPContext.GetItemDetail(self.Uri).then((item: SP.ListItem) => {
    let fieldValues = item.get_fieldValues();
    let reportType: SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue = fieldValues[reportTypeColumn];
    debugger;
    //...
});
```

At the debugger, Chrome gives:

```
reportType: Object
  Label: "Sales"
  TermGuid: "5a3b7d93-2bb4-4fef-b7a0-b870205e1d18"
  WssId: 3
  _ObjectType_: "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"
  _proto_: Object
```

However, if Sp.Taxonomy.js *is* included, the debugger point gives:

```
reportType: SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue
  _proto_: Object
    &0_1: null
    $1_1: null
    $2_1: 0
    ...
```

In this case, it appears that the reportType column is unable to extract the term. All calls to `reportType.get_label()` etc return `null` as well.

I did try to call context.load(reportType) to see if it is now something I needed to execute explicitly; however `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` is not also an `SP.ClientObject` and can't be loaded (or at least, throws an error in TypeScript).

---

Just in case it's important, here's SPContext.WebFromNewHost(), which resets the appContextSite to retrieve information from an arbitrary site collection in the farm:

```
public static WebFromNewHost(hostweburl: string): Promise<SP.Web> {
    if (SPContext._instance._clientContext.get_webRequestExecutorFactory() == null) {
        let factory: SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(SPContext.AppWebUrl);
        SPContext._instance._clientContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    }
    let appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(SPContext.ClientContext, hostweburl);
    let web: SP.Web = appContextSite.get_web();
    SPContext.ClientContext.load(web);

    return new Promise<SP.Web>((resolve, reject) => {
        SPContext.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            (sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs) => {
                resolve(web);
            },
            (sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestFailedEventArgs) => {
                reject(args.get_message());
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found a solution, although I don't quite understand it!

Originally, the taxonomy library was loaded via a plain script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Taxonomy.js"></script>
```

However, swapping this for

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.RequestExecutor.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.Taxonomy.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

and modifying my start file (knockout.js initialisation) to:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
    () => SP.SOD.executeFunc("userprofile", 'SP.UserProfiles',
        () => SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.requestexecutor.js", null,
            () => SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.taxonomy.js", null,
                () => ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel(), document.getElementById("content"))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

and now the resulting TaxonomyFieldValues are appearing!